# Design DynamoDB for Large data using array. Over 400k

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm worked with `node.js` and for record event-time and event-data, I want to use AWS `DynamoDB` Table.

single data and one-key-data schema sample like under.

```js
var want_to_update_data = [ // contain json more or same than 1
  { "event-time" : "2021-01-02 10:11:12", "event-data" : 19 },
  ...
];

var saved_data = { // DynamoDB Saved Data Sample with Key "ABCD"
  "Key" : "ABCD",
  "events" : [
    ...
    { "event-time" : "2020-12-28 09:30:17", "event-data" : 35 },
    { "event-time" : "2021-01-01 19:11:12", "event-data" : 16 },
    { "event-time" : "2021-01-02 10:11:12", "event-data" : 19 },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Upper data is only for sample. json contains more key-values.

---

For update single json, my server code likes under.

```js
app.get('/insert', req, res) {
  var update_key = req.body.update_key; // "ABCD"
  var want_to_update_data = req.body.update_data; // [ {} ]

  var updateExpression = 'SET events = list_append(events, :dl)'; // dl means data-list
  var expressionAttributeValues = {':dl' : want_to_update_data }; // dl means data-list

  AWS.config.update({
    region: "region",
    endpoint: "endpoint",
    accessKeyId: "access_key",
    secretAccessKey: "secret_key",
  });

  var params = {
    TableName: "TableName",
    Key: update_key,
    UpdateExpression: updateExpression,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expressionAttributeValues,
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
  });

  var dynamodbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  dynamodbClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if(err) { /* handle error */ }
    else { /* handle after update complete */ }
  });
});
```

Simply, It works, but AWS DynamoDB can't change over 4kb at once.
So, if array data is bigger than 4k, list_append not worked with `ValidationException: Item size to update has exceeded the maximum allowed size` error message.

---

I want to remain all events and want to sort `event-time` keys.

How can I change my DynamoDB schema?

Under code is just my guess.
Is it possible?

```js
{
  "Key" : "ABCD",
  /*
  "events" : [
    ...
    { "event-time" : "2020-12-28 09:30:17", "event-data" : 35 },
    { "event-time" : "2021-01-01 19:11:12", "event-data" : 16 },
    { "event-time" : "2021-01-02 10:11:12", "event-data" : 19 },
    ...
  ]
  */
  "events" : { // is it possible events['some-date'] could be sort-key?
    ...
    "2020-12-28 09:30:17" : 35,
    "2021-01-01 19:11:12" : 16,
    "2021-01-02 10:11:12" : 19,
    ...
  }

}

/*
  var updateExpression = 'SET events = list_append(events, :dl)'; // dl means data-list
  var expressionAttributeValues = {':dl' : want_to_update_data }; // dl means data-list
*/

  // under 2 line is just for sample. json key is not fixed
  var event_time = '2021-01-02 10:11:12';
  var single_json = want_to_update_data[event_time];

  // if number-start key is not allow(event_time), prefix append could be like "D_2021~~"
  var updateExpression = `SET events.${event_time} = :dl`;
  var expressionAttributeValues = {':dl' : single_json }; // single json
```

Thank you for read my question.

I want to create new table for save my events json datas.
(not S3. using DynamoDB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB has an item size limit of 400kb, including the attribute names.

According to [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html)

> **Number of Values in List, Map, or Set**
> There is no limit on the number of values in a List, a Map, or a Set, as long as the item containing the values fits within the 400 KB item size limit.

It sounds like your list of 4k events, plus whatever else you're saving in the item, exceeds this 400kb limit.  You can check out this [nifty calculator](https://zaccharles.github.io/dynamodb-calculator/) to get an idea of the size of your item.

Instead of storing events in a list item, you might want to store them in an item collection.

For example, instead of this:

[image]

You could store event data like this

[image]

If you need to fetch events by time, you might consider making the `event_time` your sort key.

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that I understand it properly? One-key value likes `{ "id" : "ABCD", "data" : { some json over than 400kb } }` could not be saved. right? Anyway, nifty calculator link that you provided was very helpful for me. Thanks a lot !!! @Seth Geoghegan

Comment: Well, not exactly, but you're close!  A single item in DynamoDB has a hard limit of 400kb, which includes the attribute names.  So, if you use long attribute names, it will count against your 400kb limit,  The calculator I linked in my answer takes all of that into account.

Comment: I seem to understand how much I need about 400kb limit. Actually, I backup DynamoDB data to S3 if array is too big. Sorry for my short english. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store infinitely large amounts of data in a `DynamoDB` on single Key.

Just like what you wrote, periodically back up to S3.

In my case, I use `redis-cache` for check each array size and with [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule), back-up large datas to `S3`.